# SVN icon overlays show green instead of red

Tags: svn, icons, tortoisesvn

I have a question concerning SVN:

I have some Files in a repository. 2 Users have access to those files. **User** **A** updates his working copy, makes changes and commits his changes. On his computer the little status icons change from green tick - red mark - green tick. This should be normal as I undersand.

Now **User B** opens his folder where his icon is set to the *green* tick even though he has a different copy in comparison to the repository. As I understand this would have to be *red*.

The contents of the file is updated correctly for both users.

Does anybody have any Idea as to why that is and how to solve the problem? I know that there is a windows-problem triggering all that. I tried some advices given on similar questions ( e.g. F5 or SVN Clean up ) but they don`t work.

Thank you

itelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now User B opens his folder where his icon is set to the green tick
>   even though he has a different copy in comparison to the repository.
>   As I understand this would have to be red.

No, it would not be red or orange. Working copy status icons reflect the local status only.

The initial status check looks only at your working copy, Subversion client does not poll the server for changes. When you see red file icons, it means that you have local uncommitted (i.e. unpublished) modifications in your working copy. Orange icons usually mean that there is a conflict that has to be solved. Read [TortoiseSVN Manual | How Working Copies Track the Repository](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-basics-svn.html#tsvn-basics-svn-wcrepository) and [Getting Status Information](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-1) sections.

> Does anybody have any Idea as to why that is and how to solve the
>   problem?

To my understanding this is not an issue at all. Read the documentation.